# what is indicating AGPBI error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, build, runtime-error

I saw many times AGPBI error when build a project. even it showing AGPBI error when build get successful. what is actually indicating this AGPBI error?

Answer (score 0):

These messages are issued by the Android Gradle plugin and the abbreviation means

> Android Gradle parsed build issue.

Citing from the [source code](https://github.com/zawn/android-gradle-plugin-src/blob/908b391a9c006af569dfaff08b37f8fdd6c4da89/sdk-common/src/main/java/com/android/ide/common/blame/parser/JsonEncodedGradleMessageParser.java):

```
// Android gradle parsed build issue. A prefix that is very unlikely to occur elsewhere to
// signify the rest of the line should be parsed as a json encoded {@link Message},
public static final String STDOUT_ERROR_TAG = "AGPBI: ";
```